# Multiple functions inside string with LESS

Tags: css, less

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15322900/use-function-inside-string-with-less) to this a while ago, and received a great answer. Unfortunately, this time round the answer is not sufficient, and the question is slightly more complex.

I am using [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) with the [LESSHat](http://lesshat.com/) mixins to build a theme at the moment. I have defined a number of colours as variables, and am currently trying to define a gradient using LESSHat's `.gradient()` mixin. The problem is that the mixin accepts a string as a single argument, rather than a series of arguments for each gradient parameter, for example:

```
#element {
    .gradient(~"linear-gradient(90deg, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%)");
}
```

All is well and good with the above, and I can use my variables inside the string using String Interpolation (i.e. `@{color-var}`). However, I would also like to run some functions on the variables, something like this:

```
.gradient(~"linear-gradient(top, @{green} 0%, @{green} 50%, darken(@green, 10%) 50%, darken(@green, 10%) 100%)");
```

The problem is that `darken(@green, 10%)` is never compiled, and some browsers simply interpret this color as `green`. Does anyone know the correct way to include the return of the `darken()` function inside the string above, without creating a separate variable for that?

For reference, I have tried the following to no avail:

```
.gradient(~"linear-gradient(top, @{green} 0%, @{green} 50%, "darken(@green, 10%)" 50%, "darken(@green, 10%)" 100%)");
.gradient(~"linear-gradient(top, @{green} 0%, @{green} 50%, {darken(@{green}, 10%)} 50%, {darken(@{green}, 10%)} 100%)");
```

Comment: I believe "the correct way to include the return of the `darken()` function inside the string" is _not to_ (that is, I do not believe LESS functions can _currently_ be included in a string and work; there is no "function interpolation").

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should work, it's like your first approach but you should also include the `~`:

```
.gradient(~"linear-gradient(top, @{green} 0%, @{green} 50%, " darken(@green, 10%) ~" 50%, " darken(@green, 10%) ~" 100%)");
```

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't seem to work. For example:
`.gradient(~"linear-gradient(top, @{green} 0%, " darken(@green, 10%) ~" 100%)");` compiles to `linear-gradient(top, #77cc33 0%, , #5fa329, 100%);` notice the erroneous comma...

Comment: @BenM: Just an FYI, this must be an issue with the LESSHat mixin itself (something it does with the string value), as just purely from the perspective of forming a string, the extra commas do not show up. I think this is essentially the correct way to get what you want (even though it is not technically using the function in a string).

Comment: @ScottS thanks for your comments. I investigated the problem and it seems that you're quite correct. The problem is with the mixin from LESSHat, rather than the solution provided by Lipis.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried saving the darkened color into a variable first?  Like this:

```
@darkened-green: darken(@green, 10%);
.gradient(~"linear-gradient(top, @{green} 0%, @{green} 50%, @{darkened-green} 50%, @{darkened-green} 100%)");
```

Comment: Yes, that works of course. Please see my separate note in the question, though: *Does anyone know the correct way to include the return of the darken() function inside the string above, **without creating a separate variable** for that?*